# Akka http request timeout

Tags: akka, akka-http

Using Akka http with a simple `get` returning a future from `Slick` DAO does only gives a timeout response `503 service unavailable` when the future actually completes, whereas it should just give a 503 response after timeout expires.

Below is the configuration in `application.conf`

```
include "akka-http-version"
akka.http {
   server {
     idle-timeout = 300 s
     request-timeout = 2 s
   }
}
```

If, with above configuration a request comes and repository takes, let's say `10 seconds` then the response only **after 10 seconds** is `503`, whereas we should get a 503 after `2 seconds` itself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question being asked

Answer (score 0):

The Akka behaviour works perfectly fine. The timeout has to happen on the **Future thread** (different thread of an async operation).

The main thread which starts at the beginning of the route must not be blocked for Akka to reply with a `503`, the timeout must happen on the async thread.